# Twilio call fw - twimlets forward

Tags: twilio, forward

How can I do a simple redirect to a phone number using twimlets forward?

I've used this https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward; and it works only with Twilio numbers but I want a Twilio number to be redirected to my landline number.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example of a Twilio Twimlet using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) that will forward to any number:

http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=415-555-1212.

I use exactly this format to forward one of my Twilio numbers to any one of 5 other numbers I use, including a landline, mobile, skype number and another twilio number.

If you are using something similar and its not working, perhaps be more specific - i.e. ar you doing international calls, what type of error are you getting? etc.

Perhaps logging into twilio and looking at the logs will give you a clue.

Comment: http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=40214041234 this doesn't work I've tried all possible number formats.

please give me an working example for working fw to a landline number in romania. 

they look like this 0214041234
country code: 0040

Comment: Is you twilio account enabled for internation numbers? and romania in particular? You need to look under your account->Geographic Permissions and make sure Romania is enabled.

Comment: Small note that if you want to pass an "international" number in E.164 format (i.e. +1 415 555 1212), you need to encode the "+" sign in the URL. Here's the URL you'd use: https://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=%2b1-415-555-1212 and for the 40 country code number, that would probably be https://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=%2b40214041234 . Cheers